# Eclipse RCP: When creating a plug-in based product configuration, do I need to add the Defining Plugin as a dependency as well?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I created an Eclipse plug-in project named "com.example.e4.rcp.todo" and then created a seperate "com.example.e4.rcp.todo.product" project in the same workspace. In the new product project, I created a new product configuration ("todo.product").  In this configuration's overview page, there is a button to create a "New" product definition.  When I do this, I set "Defining Plugin" to be "com.example.e4.rcp.todo".  So now, once I click synchronize, the entry for the product is added to my plug-in projects plugin.xml file.

My question is, having done all this. do I have to go into todo.product's Dependencies and add "com.example.e4.rcp.todo"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a plugin based product the Dependencies section of the .product file must list **every** plugin that you want to be included in the RCP. This includes the defining plugin and all the required Eclipse plugins.

Once you have added all your plugins to the Dependencies the 'Add Required' button should be able to add the required Eclipse plugins.